# Iterate through file with regex and multiple variables

Tags: regex, string, powershell, loops

I am trying to extract html from a text file. Here's what it looks like:

```
<html>

<cool class="what"> idk1 </cool>
<lame id="hm">idc1 </lame>
<lame id="hm"> idc2 </lame>
<lame id="hm"> idc3</lame>
<lame id="hm"> idc4 </lame>
<confused id="allTheTime"> abc1 </confused>

<cool class="what"> idk2 </cool>
<lame id="hm"> </lame>
<lame id="hm"> idc2 </lame>
<lame id="hm">  </lame>
<lame id="hm"> idc4 </lame>
<confused id="allTheTime"> abc2 </confused>

<cool class="what"> idk3 </cool>
<confused id="allTheTime"> abc3 </confused>

</html>
```

Below is my code:

```
$html = Get-Content -path 'C:\Users\bob\Desktop\tester.txt' -Raw
$wantedData1 = ($html | select-string '(?<=<cool class="what">\s+)(.*?)(?=\s+</cool>)' -allMatches | foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {$_.Value})
$wantedData2 = ($html | select-string '(?<=<lame id="hm">\s+)(.*?)(?=\s+</lame>)' -allMatches | foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {$_.Value})
$wantedData3 = ($html | select-string '(?<=<confused id="allTheTime">\s+)(.*?)(?=\s+</confused>)' -allMatches | foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {$_.Value})
write-host $wantedData1
write-host $wantedData2
write-host $wantedData3
```

The output looks like this:

```
idk1 idk2 idk3
idc2 idc4 idc2  idc4
abc1 abc2 abc3
```

I am trying to write something thats gives me an output like this:

```
idk1
idc1
idc2
idc3
idc4
abc1

idk2
idc2
idc4
abc2

idk3
abc3
```

The data for the `<cool>` and `<confused>` tag occur one time for each iteration but the values of the `<lame>` tag may not exist or there may be between 1 to 5 `<lame>` tags. I mention this because one of my other queries would break if the tag was null. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your HTML text is also valid XML, which makes parsing easier:

```sh
# Simulate reading from an XML file.
# To read from an actual file, use:
#    ($xmlDoc = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path file.xml))
[xml] $xmlDoc = @'
<html>

<cool class="what"> idk1 </cool>
<lame id="hm">idc1 </lame>
<lame id="hm"> idc2 </lame>
<lame id="hm"> idc3</lame>
<lame id="hm"> idc4 </lame>
<confused id="allTheTime"> abc1 </confused>

<cool class="what"> idk2 </cool>
<lame id="hm"> </lame>
<lame id="hm"> idc2 </lame>
<lame id="hm">  </lame>
<lame id="hm"> idc4 </lame>
<confused id="allTheTime"> abc2 </confused>

<cool class="what"> idk3 </cool>
<confused id="allTheTime"> abc3 </confused>

</html>
'@

# Get the inner text from all <html> child nodes and
# trim surrounding whitespace from each.
$xml.html.ChildNodes.InnerText.Trim()
```

The above yields the following (which doesn't fully match what you state in your question, but I presume is what you meant); you can capture it in an array of string simply by prepending something like `$strings =`  to the `foreach` statement:

```
idk1
idc1
idc2
idc3
idc4
abc1
idk2

idc2

idc4
abc2
idk3
abc3
```